# Fix "Developer mode required" to run react-native app without turning on developer mode for all users in IOS

Tags: android, ios, iphone, react-native

I'm developing an Mobile app for IOS and Android using react-native.

The android app is working even the developer mode is turned off, but in IOS you can install it but it also needs to turn on the developer mode so that you can run it. I don't want to every IOS user be required to enable developer mode when it deployed.

I searched a lot and all the solutions tells to turned it on.

Please guide me where can I fix it. I don't have any idea where should I look for the file to be fix. I'm using react-native.